# Run an rspec "before" block before rails initializers run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, initializer

I would like to run an rspec `before` block to set some stuff up *before* the Rails initializers run, so I can test what an initializer should be doing.  Is this possible?

Comment: What are you trying to test the initialization of? Can you just new up the object in question on your own? You can always dig into the source if needed I guess: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Comment: Our code reads an external file and sets a variable based on its contents.  This happens in an initializer.  I want to have tests that assure that it reading the file, setting the var, and also handling the case of a missing file, etc.  I can do lots of hackery to pretend things are happening, but the closer I can get to actual operation (i.e. minimum hackery), the better.  The best solution is to be able to create the file before the initializers run, but I can't seem to be able to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If the logic in your initializers is complex enough it should be tested, you should extract it into a helper that you can isolate and test without being in the context of the initializer.

complex_initializer.rb

```
config.database.foo = calculate_hard_stuff()
config.database.bar = other_stuff()
```

You could extract that into a testable helper (lib/config/database.rb)

```
module Config::DatabaseHelper
  def self.generate_config
    {:foo => calculate_hard_stuff, :bar => other_stuff)
  end

  def calculate_hard_stuff
    # Hard stuff here
  end
end
```

...then just wire up the configuration data in your initializer

```
db_config_values = Config::DatabaseHelper.generate_config
config.database.foo = db_config_values[:foo]
config.database.bar = db_config_values[:bar]
```

...and test the complex configuration determination/calculation in a separate test where you can isolate the inputs.

```
describe Config::DatabaseHelper do
  describe '.calculate_hard_stuff' do
    SystemValue.stubs(:config => value)
    Config::DatabaseHelper.calculate_hard_stuff.should == expected_value
  end
end
```