# How to tell RSpec to restart Rails before an example is run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, automated-tests, rails-engines

Is it possible to tell rspec to restart Rails before an example is run?  I'm building an Engine that hooks into the Rails initialization process and the users can make some configuration changes, in an initializer, that impact how Rails and the Engine are configured.  I want to be able to simulate those configuration changes, restart rails and test the result.

Comment: See below. Although not a practical answer, I hope it helps you arrive at an solution. If you have any issues, add more details regarding what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't done this feat yet, but as best practice I think your engine tests should be part of the engine and should have minimal dependencies.

Some approaches I've seen and believe you should try and combine:

1. Mock a [minimal parent rails app](http://abangratz.github.io/blog/2013/07/17/minimal-rails-app-for-gem-development/) to test your engine.
2. Write [multiple dummy apps to test with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752774/strategies-for-gem-tests-to-ensure-the-gem-works-with-rails-3-x-and-4-0).
3. Instead of loading the entire rails application, you can [split spec_helper and rails_helper](http://codecrate.com/2014/05/maintainable-rspec-helper.html) in [smaller parts](http://belighted.com/en/blog/how-we-test-our-rails-projects-2-3), also [gaining in setup time](http://paul.annesley.cc/2012/03/fast-rspec-slash-rails-tiered-spec-helper-dot-rb/).
4. You can write [custom rake tasks to switch environment before spawning a new test thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090176/how-do-i-force-rails-env-in-a-rake-task).
5. You can also overwrite at runtime the configuration values which reflect in your test (plus: use [dependency injection](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/inject-that-rails-configuration-dependency)!).
6. If your initializer is complex enough, you could [extract it in a testable helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557636/run-an-rspec-before-block-before-rails-initializers-run) and [wire it up in your test initializers](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2013/07/23/testing-code-in-a-rails-initializer/).
7. Also, there seems to be a gem for that: [Combustion](https://github.com/pat/combustion).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  There are some great suggestions here.